# how to use linux commands on windows with cmder?

Tags: linux, shell, cmd, command

I usually use cmder because it recognizes windows and linux commands. however for some reason the linux commands are not recognized like `ls` and `touch`.

- I do use the full version not the mini

Comment: There are several third party terminal applications which can work with multiple environments, however I doubt they all come with a complete 'nix command line environment built in. The usual way is to install your environments, then configure your terminal to be able to access each. Regardless your question is a software related one, not a programming issue within the scope defined for StackOverflow, and is therefore off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have bash installed on your computer?
This will allow you to use Linux/Unix command lines on Windows.
If so you can use the integration for cmder [Wiki](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Integrating-Cygwin)